# Tornado with single page application

Tags: vuejs2, tornado

as mentioned in the title, I’m currently trying to develop a single page application with vuejs(front end) and tornado(backend). The front end is basically one small index.html file that runs a giant JavaScript file that also includes client side routing.

The problem I have is with StaticFileHandler, which I’m currently using to serve my index.html file. Every time the URL is changed from the browser, there is always a split second that it shows index.html before the client  routes it to the correct URL.
I’m wondering if there is a better way to handle this so that the URL is updated once by the front end client instead of going through the redirection.

I’m still quite new to tornado and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try and server your index file with a regular `RequestHandler` class, instead of the `StaticFileHander`?